# NAudio giving Buffer Full when used with TCP audio stream

Tags: naudio, naudio-framework

I have written the following code which reads data from a TCP Client and attempts to write it to a BufferedWaveProvider by using AddSamples.  The audio that is read is also written to an audio file.  A TCP Client connects every 30 seconds, sends some audio and then disconnects. After about 40 iterations, this method fails on AddSamples with a Buffer Full exception and the audio player shows PlayBackStopped.

The audio "file" waveWriteRecvd contains all of the received audio despite it no longer playing to the speaker.

```
       private static void OnServerDataReceived(ServerThread st, byte[] data)
        {

            if (m_DictionaryServerDatas.ContainsKey(st))
            {

                ServerThreadData stData = m_DictionaryServerDatas[st];
                stData.Receive(st, data);
                int size = data.Length;
                try
                {
                    if (size > 0)
                    {
                        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(data, 0, size);

                        if (waveWriteRecvd == null)
                        {
                            Open_WriteRecvd();
                        }
                        waveWriteRecvd.WriteData(data, 0, size);
                        waveWriteRecvd.Flush();
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception exbuf)
                {
                    LogMessage("Error adding samples to Line-Out buffer " + exbuf.Message + "\r\n");
                }
            }
        }
```

I have attempted to stop and dispose of the BufferedWaveProvider, the wave file stream and the player to no avail.  The playing of the audio through the speaker stops after roughly 20 - 40 client connections passing audio.

```
            if (wvin != null)
            {
                wvin.StopRecording();
                wvin.Dispose();
                wvin = null;
            }
            if (bufferedWaveProvider != null)
            {
                bufferedWaveProvider.ClearBuffer();
                bufferedWaveProvider = null;
            }
            if (player != null)
            {
                player.Stop();
                player.Dispose();
                player = null;
            }
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the C# application is a C# Forms app under Visual Studio 2022.  NAudio is version 1.9.0.0, runtime v2.0.50727.